# Is there a rich ftp client library for Python?

Tags: python, ftp

I'm familiar with ftplib and it works great for simple interface but I need file properties and basically a rich ftp client.  does anyone know of a good ftp client library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the MLSD command.  You have to parse it yourself but it's fairly easy.

```
# Note that portions of MLSD data are case insensitive...
def parseinfo(info):
    for fact in info.split(';'):
        if not fact:
            continue
        name, value = fact.split('=', 1)
        yield name.lower(), value

ftp = ftplib.FTP(host, user, passwd)
dirinfo = {}
def callback(line):
    info, fname = line.split(' ', 1)
    dirinfo[fname] = dict(parseinfo(info))
ftp.retrlines('MLSD {}'.format(path), callback)
print(dirinfo)
```

That's about as rich as FTP gets.

Answer (score 1):

The [ftputil](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac) could be what you are looking for:

> The FTPHost objects generated with ftputil allow many operations similar to those of ​os and ​os.path.

The API supports well [file information gathering](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation#retrieving-information-about-directories-files-and-links).